# Redirect subdomain to subdomain Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, redirection

Let's say I have a web server with IP address: 1.2.3.4.

I also have 2 subdomains:

```
 sth.city.eu
 inf.xyz.city.eu
```

I'm using apache 2 on Ubuntu Server. Here's my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sth.city.eu
    ServerAlias sth.city.eu
    ServerAlias inf.xyz.city.eu
    ServerAlias www.inf.xyz.city.eu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/city/

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/city/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_city.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_city.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to make something like this: if someone will go to `inf.xyz.city.eu`, server should automatically redirect him to `sth.city.eu` (change the url). Is that possible - how can I do this? I've searched google and found `Redirect`, tried to use it like this:

```
Redirect http://inf.xyz.city.eu http://www.sth.city.eu
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can solve this by setting up 2 vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName inf.xyz.city.eu
    ServerAlias www.inf.xyz.city.eu
    Redirect / http://sth.city.eu/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sth.city.eu
    ServerAlias sth.city.eu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost      
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: @mazix: Can you verify that the alias module is enabled? You can check with `sudo apache2ctl -M`

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: @maxix, you need to remove the ServerAlias entries from your main (non-vHosts) configuration, and change the ServerName to _default_. Don't use the main configuration anymore - move it into the appropriate vHost as shown by Mikolan.

Comment: @roaima: could you please give an example of this? I just sterted with Apache and it's (at least now) a bit complicated to me).

Comment: It may look obvious, but did you restart apache after having modified the configuration ?

Comment: The thing you're talking about is called **Canonical Hostname**, and is a common enough request that it's used as one of the [examples in the mod_rewrite documentation][1].

  [1]: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_rewrite, you can use RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inf\.xyz\.city\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sth.city.eu/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

What @mikolan was saying is:

in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` you should have 2 `vhost` files:

1. file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sth.city.eu`

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sth.city.eu
    ServerAlias www.sth.city.eu
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost      

    DocumentRoot /var/www/city/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/city/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sth.city.eu.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sth.city.eu.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

2. file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/inf.xyz.city.eu`

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName inf.xyz.city.eu
  ServerAlias www.inf.xyz.city.eu
  Redirect / http://sth.city.eu/

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/inf.xyz.city.eu.error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/inf.xyz.city.eu.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, both files are created in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, and are enabled with

```
sudo a2ensite inf.xyz.city.eu
sudo a2ensite sth.city.eu
sudo service apache2 restart
```

- Every time you enable/disable site/module a `reload` is enough, but while testing, `restart` is more safe (*peace mind*)
- Check if the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) is enabled (should be by default)
- Check the logs to see what errors you get: insufficient permissions, you don't even get the requests?