# Redirect subdomain to subdomain in HTTPS with Apache2

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have those subdomains:

```
link.domain.com
links.domain.com
```

I want to redirect the `link.domain.com` to `links.domain.com`. For this, I used the same method as described here : [Redirect subdomain to subdomain Apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/663423/redirect-subdomain-to-subdomain-apache2) and it works.

I installed a TLS certificate for `links.domain.com` with Let's Encrypt and I can perfectly access `links.domain.com` in HTTPS. I would like the redirection from `link.domain.com` to `links.domain.com` to be also effective in HTTPS.

Here is my conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/links/
      ServerName links.domain.com

      <Directory "/var/www/links/">
         Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_links.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_links.log combined 

      # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
      # alert, emerg.
      LogLevel warn

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/links.domain.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/links.domain.com/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I already tried the following :

- Adding

  `ServerAlias link.domain.com
   RedirectMatch permanent ^link.domain.com/(.*)$ https://links.domain.com/$1`

  after the `ServerName links.domain.com` line.
- Adding

  `<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName link.domain.com
      RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ https://links.domain.com/$1
   </VirtualHost>`

  before and after the already defined VirtualHost.

No one worked.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the SSL configuration in both `VirtualHost`s, and `RedirectMatch` isn't necessary. Try:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName link.example.com

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/links.example.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/links.example.com/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      Redirect / https://links.example.com/
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Please notice that you will still get a `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` TLS error if you don't also have `link.example.com` in the *Subject Alternative Name* of your certificate.

Comment: Should I set this VirtualHost before or after the one I already have ? Or in another file ?

Comment: The order doesn't matter for other `VirtualHost`s than the one you would like to have as the _default_. Whether you want to have it on the same file or another in `sites-available/` depends on your naming convention. I usually add separated files only for _canonical_ server names i.e. one file per site, and have all redirects in the same file. Separated files are useful when you want to be able to separately enable / disable the `VirtualHost` with `a2ensite`/ `a2dissite`.